# Get Resource Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to get resource from folder resources/key?

I did like this:

```
String Key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("key/private.pem").toURI())));
```

And it doesn't work when I build the project into a jar. So I'm looking for another way to do this.
Can you please tell me how to get the resource?

```
    private PublicKey getPublicKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {

        String key = getPublicKeyContent().replaceAll("\\n", "")
                .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key));

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        return kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
      }



      private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        String key = getPrivateKeyContent().replaceAll("\\n", "")
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key));

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this util method which uses spring framework core and util packages.

```
    public static String getResourceFileContent(String resourcePath) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(resourcePath);
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(resourcePath);
        try {
            byte[] bytes = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
            return new String(bytes);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            log.error("Failed to parse resource file : " + resourcePath, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `/` to the resource path and use `InputStream`:

```java
public class Foo {

    public static byte[] readResourceFile(String path) throws IOException {
        if (path.charAt(0) != '/')
            path = '/' + path;

        try (InputStream in = Foo.class.getResourceAsStream(path)) {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        }
    }

}
```

Remember that when you build a `jar` file, the `resource` will be copied to the root of the jar file.

This is the sources:

```
Foo
|--> src
      |--> main
      |     |--> java
      |     |     |--> com
      |     |           |--> stackoverflow
      |     |                  |--> Foo.java
      |     |--> resources
      |     |     |--> key
      |                 |--> private.pem
      |--> test
```

This is a `foo.jar` file

```
foo.jar
|--> META_INF
|--> com
|     |--> stackoverflow
|           |--> Foo.class
|--> key
      |--> private.pem
```

And the root of the `foo.jar` is a `/`. So the full path to the resouces is `/key/private.pem`.

Comment: It's not in the classroom. These are the encryption keys that are located separately in the spring boot resources folder

Comment: And this is the string

Comment: It does not matter

Comment: Your code returns bytes. I need to return a string, not a byte.

Comment: `String str = new String(byte[])`

Comment: Look above, I've updated the post. These are the methods that receive the text.

Comment: getPrivateKeyContent() and getPublicKeyContent()